# *num++ causes strange behavior

Tags: c, pointers, increment

I was creating a function to increment a pointer variable and another variable:

```
// num = 3
void test(int *num) {
    printf("Num = %d\n", *num); // "Num = 3"
    
    *num++;
    int x = *num;

    x++;    // Does nothing
    x += 1; // Also does nothing

    printf("Num = %d\n", *num); // "Num = 0"
    printf("x = %d\n", x); // "x = 0"
}

int main() {
    int num = 3;
    test(&num);
    return 0;
}
```

I was curious why `*num++` sets the variable to 0. Later I set `int x = *num` and I can no longer increment `x`. You can see in the function where I attempt `x++` and `x += 1` and neither increase the value. What's happening here?

**Note:** The solution here is `*num += 1`, which works fine. But why is it working this way?

Answer (score 4):

> I was curious why *num++ sets the variable to 0.

It doesn't.

`*num++` is equivalent to `*(num++)` i.e. you're dereferencing it
(i.e. `*num`) and incrementing the pointer (which would then point to one past the `num` location). So you're not accessing what you seem to have intended.

This could be undefined behaviour if `num + 1` isn't part of the same object or valid (e.g. an array). If the passed object was just an `int` object (e.g. `int n = 3; test(&n);`) then it's certainly undefined.

> Note: The solution here is *num += 1, which works fine. But why is it working this way?

Because that doesn't alter `num`.

As a general note, statements like `*num++`, though can be written correctly & legally, is always error prone. Thus should be avoided.